# ArchLinux "Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists"

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez

I attempted to connect to a device doing:

```
bluetoothctl
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on

trust [device id]
pair [device id]
```

Which gave me the error:
`Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists`

I wasn't able to find any other issues online with this error.

I then tried doing:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

which failed, and I got the same error. I also tried rebooting. If you need anything else specified, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

`Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists` this, seem to happen when you already have the device paired.
You can probably just connect to it, or alternatively pair it again after you remove that device by typing

```
] remove [ some device id ]
```